# Why do YouTube videos start late?

Tags: youtube, google-chrome

The only problem is that YouTube videos don't start immediately. Watching animated circle icon - instead of the video - is annoying. When the video starts, there is no problem with it, it loads fast.

[Here is the video how it looks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo6YlIEUccs)

Comment: Probably you have a slow network at your place. Where you located at?

Comment: Try updating / re-installing Adobe Flash.

Comment: I noticed there is no delay in stealth mode of Chrome. I think some extension causes this; ie AdBlock, YouTube Download, or any other. I'll check.

Comment: I disabled all extensions. No luck. I did sign out. No luck. No problem with IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Your Internet speed is too low, as you said animated circle, that's indicating you that the video is currently buffering, in another words, it is loading, so whenever you open a video page on YouTube, play it, than immediately pause it, let the video buffer, you'll see a grey line filling, once it's filled, you can play your video without any interruptions.

Comment: No. It also starts buffering too late. In stealth mode, everything is ok. No problem with IE8 too.